# How to move /usr folder and replace it with saved copy

Tags: shell, files

If I made a backup of /usr with:

```
# cp -r /usr /usrRESERVE1
```

how can i switch it back after some time:

```
1# mv usr usrRESERVE2
2# mv usrRESERVE1 usr
```

second command will not work because `mv` is inside `/usr/bin/mv` and it does not exist after first line execution.

//answering to my self...

Solution 1: Using 'mount --bind' as dummy-var

```
(pointed by comment of user MarkPlotnick):

# mount --bind /usrRESERVE1 /usr  #usr points --to--> usrRES1 from now
# mkdir /dummy
# mount --bind / /dummy           #contains original root folders
# cd /dummy ; mv usr usrRESERVE2
#             mv usrRESERVE1 usr
# cd / ; umount dummy ; umount usr ; rmdir dummy
```

Solution 2: using single process - moving tool

```
# package manager install mmv
# mmv /usr /usrRESERVE1 -- /usrRESERVE2 /usr
```

Comment: What exactly happens when you run `/usrRES/bin/mv`? Error message please. (I would guess you've also lost your shared libraries.)

Comment: and result of `ldd mv` also. You might need to edit LD_LIBRARY_PATH var as well.

Comment: @roaima ... zsh said something like 'no such command nor file' but i will check again now, after both of you think that command should    work

Comment: @Omer, I get similar error messages with ksh, but it works for me with bash. Open a bash shell and try my answer below in that shell again.

Comment: @Janis i just tried bash, same result '/usrRES/bin/mv no such file or directory'

Comment: maybe /usr/bin/mv is still in hash from shell, have you tried ? ( `/usr/bin/mv usrRES usr` )

Comment: @Archemar i will try :) ... but i think that you pointed LDD well to me, and that i just need do redirect links of 3 libraries libattr libc and libacl .so.1

Comment: "My full problem indeed was to move my usr to SDCARD because i was running out of space:" WHAT !? move `/home` or `/usr/local` or  `/opt` or `/data` but not `/usr` !

Comment: size of usr 2GB size of var 2gb, size of home+opt+data ... 100mb.

Comment: You can use `/bin/busybox` to move or copy without needing any shared libraries. I'd still do all this from a rescue CD or single-user mode, because any time you remove stuff from `/usr`, even for a moment, programs may fail. If this is just an academic exercise, then the procedure would roughly be to  copy (not mv) /usr to the new filesystem, unmount the new filesystem, mount it on top of /usr, restart all processes with open /usr files, use mount --bind to mount the old /usr somewhere, then clean it out.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick yes, that is what am i after. it is academic research and it was a very real pain for me to reboot system 100 times just to make a tmp=a; a=b; b=tmp; switch. busybox depends on libc.so.6 and mount --bind could be a solution ... can you provide an answer with it?

Comment: I can try to set up a VM and come up with a tested solution. What distro and version are you using?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick i am using archlinux and everything is inside usr, lib is link to usr/lib ... cp -r usr usrRES; mount --bind usrRES usr; works great and it is 50% of problem solved... how to delete underlaying /usr that mount --bind hides